# PHP fight system runs infinitely?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to create a simple fighting system in PHP. Here is the code.

```
<?php
$my_atk = 20;
$my_def = 25;
$my_hp = 100;

$enemy_atk = 30;
$enemy_def = 15;
$enemy_hp = 80;

while($my_hp > 0 || $enemy_hp > 0) { 
    $enemyDef = intval($my_atk - $enemy_def / 2);
    $my_damage = rand(1,$enemyDef);

    $myDef = intval($enemy_atk - $my_def / 2);
    $enemy_damage = rand(1,$myDef);

    $my_hp_after = $my_hp - $enemy_damage;
    $enemy_hp_after = $enemy_hp - $my_damage;
    echo "Enemy damages you <b>$enemy_damage</b> (your hp <b>$my_hp_after</b> )<br>";
    echo "You damage enemy <b>$my_damage</b> (enemy hp <b>$enemy_hp_after</b>)<hr>";

    if($my_hp < 1) {
        echo "Enemy win the battle";
    }else{
        echo "You win the battle!";
    }
}
?>
```

When I run it, it's lasts infinitely...

Why does it run infinitely?

Comment: A question should contain at least, well, a question.

Comment: Tip: Use `$me = array("atk" => 20, "def" => 15, "hp" => 80);` instead of declaring 3 variables starting with "my".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a variable `$my_hp_after` and `$enemy_hp_after` but you never change `$my_hp` or `$enemy_hp` therefore the loop `while($my_hp > 0 || $enemy_hp > 0)` lasts forever

Comment: Thx!!! Working!!! But I have a new question, what's the best way to set the winner? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the value `$my_hp` and `$enemy_hp`. THat's why the value is zero everytime and so the while loop lasts forever.